# Displaying topics/categories related ads

Tags: advertising

Is there any advertising company that allow webmasters to decide on general ad topics (such as "Entertainment", "Autos and vehicles", "Arts", etc.) to be displayed for a user visiting on a website?
I know you can choose specific ad campaigns to show to users, or let the advertising company decide for you which ads to show. But I am looking for an option to ask for the advertsing company to show me ads based on categories/topics.

Thanks.

Frank

Answer (score 1):

This may not exactly be what you are looking for but the [category filtering feature](http://adsense.blogspot.com/2010/03/troubleshooting-tips-part-iv-ad.html) in Google Adsense lets you block up to [11 categories](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93462). So while you may not be able to precisely pick the category you need, you will able to block those you don't need.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this feature.. however, as you said, I was wondering if there is any service that lets you pick the desired category